# How do you print the final result in a single line?

Tags: python

I am solving a problem for a challenge:

Question:

**Write a program to extract words from a chapter and put them together into a new paragraph. Your program should take every fifth word from the first 200 words of the chapter, then print them out.**
I have managed to extract every 5th word but I can't print it in a single line.

here's the code I have :

```
file = input('Chapter file: ')
with open(file, 'r') as chapter:
  final = chapter.read()
  x = final.split()
for i in range(0, 200, 5):
  combined = (x[i])
  print(' '.join(combined))
```

here's how the output should look.
[image: output]

here's how mine looks:
[image: output2]

I just need to combine all the words and print in one single line.

Comment: `combined` is currently a single word (`x[i]`). You need some way to create a collection of _all_ words (every 5th word) then `' '.join` that. Perhaps creating a list from your for loop then calling `join` once on that? As an aside, you're currently `print`ing to console and not writing to an output file so that would also need adjusted if that's to be in a file.

Comment: print automatically puts a newline at the end. use print(foo, end='')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the fifth words in a list during the loop and join them after it. Below I show some modifications in your code to achieve this:

```
file = input('Chapter file: ')
with open(file, 'r') as chapter:
  final = chapter.read()
  x = final.split()
combined = []
for i in range(0, 200, 5):
  combined.append(x[i])

print(' '.join(combined))
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for a loop

```
print(*x[:200:5])
```

and that's safer, doesn't crash when there are too few words

Answer (score -2):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-print-without-newline-in-python

```
print("Apple" , end ="," )
print("Mango", end =",")
print("Banana")
```

I don't use python but a quick search got me to that page.